# What is Root View Controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode

When we do things like

[self.window addSubview:switchViewController.view];

Are we setting switchViewController as the rootViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually no. rootViewController is a main controller. Callbacks such as *didReceiveMemoryWarning* will be sent to rootViewController only. And it must decide to whom it is addressed.

A window contain any amount of views. Some of them have UIViewControllers, some don't. So *[self.window addSubview:switchViewController.view];* just add a view to a window, it doesn't know anything about its controller. The controllers should be manipulated by a rootViewController. The only way to set switchViewController as the rootViewController is to invoke something like *self.rootViewController = switchViewController;* in your AppDelegate file.

Comment: Ah so rootViewController is a property of AppDelegate. That thing shouldn't change right?

Comment: Yes, it is. That thing should be set only once - when your application launches. You can set it manually or from nib file - it doesn't matter.

Comment: @KonstantinChugalinskiy it means every time I want to switch to next view I have to make its view controller a root view controller?